# How do I edit a specific line of a file in java without creating a temp file?

Tags: java

I have gotten a concept from my friend who is able to use use an array to edit a line in text file. However, when I implement it in my code, it removes the entire content of my text file instead of replacing a specific line with my new input.

This is my current code:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      
        String tblCategory = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String tblID = jTextField2.getText();
        String tblName = jTextField3.getText();
        String tblPrice = jTextField4.getText();

        ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("src\\food.txt")) {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(fr);
                String line;
                String[] lineArr;

                while((line=reader.nextLine()) !=null) {
                    lineArr = line.split(",");
                    if(lineArr[1].equals(tblID)) {
                        //String category = lineArr[1];

                        tempArray.remove(lineArr[1] + "," + lineArr[2] + "," + lineArr[3]);



                        tempArray.add(tblCategory + "," +tblID + "," +tblName+ "," + tblPrice);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Food Details Updated Successfully!");
                        jTextField2.setText("");
                        jTextField3.setText("");
                        jTextField4.setText("");
                    } else {
                        tempArray.add(line);
                    }
                }

                fr.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try{
            try (PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("src\\food.txt")) {
                for (String str : tempArray) {
                    pr.println(str);
                }
                pr.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        
        
    }
```

This is the content of my text file:

```
Category/Food ID/Food Name/Price (RM)
rice, R1, Curry Rice, 10
rice, R2, Chicken Rice, 8
rice, R3, Fried Rice, 8
rice, R4, Cheese Bake Rice, 12
noodle, N1, Beef Noodle, 10
noodle, N2, Mee Goreng, 7
burger, B1, Chicken Burger, 15
drink, D1, Ice Lemon Tea, 6
drink, D2, Milo, 6
drink, D3, Apple Juice, 6
drink, D4, 100 Plus, 3
drink, D5, Milk Tea, 5
noodle,N3,Meehoon,6
noodle,N4,Noodle Soup,12
noodle,N5,Laksa,10
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've spent almost 2 days on trying to get this code correct. I've referred to many online sources but it can't be implemented to my code.

Comment: There is no safe way to do this.  By "safe" I mean "doesn't corrupt the file if interrupted at the wrong time".

Comment: Comment: you are squashing exceptions.  This is a really bad idea.  And it could be why your code is not working.

Comment: Easy if you treat the file as a [list of strings](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/40-string-list)